# Update Wifi drivers

Tags: drivers

After searching google i seem to be going round in circles and getting nowhere. I am a newbie to Ubuntu so here goes.
I have just purchased a Dell XPS13 laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 loaded on it, the problem is the wifi connection keeps dropping out. Im assuming its a wifi network card driver is the issue. Its a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174. Can anyone give any advice on how to update the driver?

Comment: Please could you include the things you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novices but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: hi , i have done as you mentioned, it returned 100% yet i can`t see any information that it has collected. It mentioned the following - Last modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.